# Laravel Nova not showing userTimezone as documented

Tags: php, laravel, datetime, laravel-nova

I have a question that has been bothering me all afternoon.

with Laravel Nova, when using the DateTime class in a resource:

```
DateTime::make('End', 'end_date')->required(),
```

It automatically displays in the local timezone (https://nova.laravel.com/docs/3.0/resources/date-fields.html). But, when i read the docs, it says to set the userTimezone in the boot method of the service provider, to define the timezone for the resources:

```
Nova::userTimezone(function (Request $request) {
    // app.timezone = 'UTC'
    return 'Europe/Warsaw';
});
```

I have done this, but it's still showing the timezone in nova on all resources as the local timezone, and not the specified timezone.

Things to note:

Cache cleared:

```
php artisan config:cache
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
```

reloaded Nova and rebuilt the pages.

My question then is, how do you make it so that Nova DateTime resources are all in a specified timezone?

Comment: Have you ever managed to solve this?

Comment: @AttilaFulop I never solved this.

Answer (score -1):

You should call this `Nova::userTimezone` in the `boot` method of your application's `NovaServiceProvider`.

```
use Laravel\Nova\Nova;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

/**
 * Bootstrap any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    Nova::userTimezone(function (Request $request) {
        return $request->user()->timezone;
    });
}
```

Comment: Thats exactly what I have done.. but its not working. Its still just returning the User Timezone, not the specified one as per my code example

Comment: Do you call `use Laravel\Nova\Nova;` in your  `NovaServiceProvider`?

Comment: yes. I have. Im using the standard NovaServiceProvider.php that comes with Nova

Comment: Check `dd($request->user()->timezone);` in your `NovaServiceProvider` and show the result

Comment: if i dd('something') before the Nova::userTimezone block, i can see it.. and if i put dd('something') after i can see it.. but if i dd('anything') inside that block, the site behaves as normal and nothing is output to the screen.

Comment: `Nova::userTimezone(function (Request $request) { dd($request->user()->timezone); });`

Comment: that is exactly what i did.. and the site continues as normal with. i mentioned the other things i did, so you can see that it works pre and post that method call inside boot().

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220093/discussion-between-mike-and-sobir).

Comment: I read documentation of Nova and It said : In addition, users may always set dates in their local timezone. The dates will automatically be converted to your application's "server-side" timezone as defined by the timezone option in your **app configuration file**.  So you go to `config/app.php` and you change `'timezone'`

Comment: You set `UTC+2` in your `'timezone'` like `'timezone' => 'UTC+2'`

Comment: Then put `Nova::userTimezone(function (Request $request) {return $request->user()->timezone;});`. It works

Comment: Ive tried both of these things. Now I can confirm by doing this, you end up with the datetime being stored on the server (db) in the time zone configured, but it is converted and displayed in the nova resource in the local time. The desired outcome is that Nova displays the datetime resource as the same time stored in the db.